# Is there a known implementation that enables mongo to work with Apache Lucene (like mongo does with Atlas search)?

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas

I was wondering if there is some package/docker that gives the functionality that mongo gives with Atlas search using Apache lucene behind the scene.
Practically, I want to have a small self-hosted docker (can't work with Atals) with mongo and lucene that sync with each other and doing the text search when needed.